# How to block certain characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I am writing a program that takes the text written in a text document called datafile.txt, then prints what is in the file. The text that is in the file is is "Hello World", but the text that prints is "['Hello World']" How do i make it so the characters [, ], and ' do not appear.

```
file = open("datafile.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
SaveDir = lines
print SaveDir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this python code,

```
import os
file = open("/path/datafile.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
str = ''.join(lines)
print str  # => Hello World
```

`.join()` function is used to convert a list into string. It prints the file contents as it is without displaying it in  list.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `file.readlines()` returns a *list of strings*  - one for each line in the file - rather than a single string. The `['` and `']` characters are just python's way of indicating the containing list object. It doesn't know ahead of time that your file only contains a single line.

You can print the individual strings (in this case there is only one) by looping over the list e.g.

```
for SaveDir in lines :
    print SaveDir
```

Comment: How this have to do with `gtk` or `glade` ? Isn't this clearly an I/O python question and so, off-topic?

Comment: no luck, the same output occurred @hakermania

Comment: Or just use `.read()` which is preferred over `.readlines()` anyway.